# golang check length of a slice if it is a slice map[string]interface{}

Tags: go, reflection, slice

I want to see if the type of `v` is a `slice`. If so, I wish to check the length of it.

```
var a = make(map[string]interface{})

a["a"] = 1
a["b"] = []string{"abc", "def"}
a["c"] = []int{1,2,3}

for k, v := range a {
    if reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        t.Log("Length of map", k, len(v)) // invalid argument v (type interface {}) for len
    }
}
```

How do I check the length of my slice, now that I know it is a slice?

Expected output:

```
Length of map b 2
Length of map c 3
```

Answer (score 4):

`v` is still a `interface{}`, which you cannot apply `len()` to. You can use reflection to get the length with `reflect.ValueOf(v).Len()`.

Comment: Note that Len() will panic here if v's type is not an array, slice, channel, map, or string.  To make sure it won't panic, make sure you keep your `reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind()` check.

Comment: Yes. In the question he's already checking the type is a slice.

Comment: Yeppers, saw that after posting, edited comment to suite.